# python dictionaries values and keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I've got dictionary called humans. I want to loop through that dictionary and if value is less than 20 print dictionary key.

```
humans = {"Danny": 33, "Jenny": 22, "Jackie": 12, "Ashley": 33}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your description of the problem is almost a perfect pseudo-code for how you would implement that:

```
# I've got dictionary called humans. 
humans = {"Danny": 33, "Jenny": 22, "Jackie": 12, "Ashley": 33}

for key, value in humans.items():  # I want to loop through that dictionary 
    if value < 20:                 # and if value is less than 20
        print(key)                 # print dictionary key.
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for k, v in humans.items():
   if v > 20:
      print(k)
```

Or, a more pythonic way:

```
print([k for k, v in humans.items() if v > 20])
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, using generator expressions:

```
result = (k for k, v in humans.items() if v > 20)
print(', '.join(result))
```

I used commas as separators, if you need each item in a different line simply substitute `', '` with `'\n'`.

Comment: It's a simple matter of adding a print statement, there it is ;)

Answer (score 3):

Loop over `items()`.

You can use comprehension (no need to use `[ ]` as it is in parenthesis already):

```
print(k for k,v in humans.items() if v > 20)
```

or really loop:

```
for k,v in humans.items():
    if v > 20:
       print(k)
```